# Can my graphics card cause Steam games to crash?

Tags: steam, no-mans-sky, graphics-card, dishonored-2

Two games from my Steam library crash whenever I try to launch them: *No Man's Sky* and *Dishonored 2*. The *No Man's Sky* crashes immediately after opening. *Dishonered 2* crashes after all the logos, right after the second loading screen appears. I've tried both **verifying game files and deleting download cache**. My next theory was that my graphics card is to blame. It is a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 and it is less than the minimal requirements for both games. However, while it is not enough to play Fallout 4 either, I've never experienced similar problems with that game. Moreover, all these games have launched without crashing on my pretty lowspec aluminium laptop.

**Does this crashing really happen because of my graphics card? What other reasons could there be?
Thanks!**

Update: I have reinstalled Steam, but it didn't help. :\

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Steam?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is the version of DirectX being supported by the graphiccard and maybe not compatible with the game. But someone else has to dive into that, got no time for that atm.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - I have the latest DirectX for Win7 installed

Comment: @McLemore - I wanted to hear what other options I have before doing this, kind of scared of everything breaking if I do. Will do it and post the results at some point I guess

Comment: @АннаСуханова that doesn't matter much if you Graphiccard doesn't support it. See the answer of SamJ.

Comment: How much RAM do you have, what's your processor? Full stats would help us determine things more accurately. It could be any number of reasons aside from the graphics card.

Comment: For the NMS loading problem, check the config files: open them using notepad. If any of them do not look like text files (they look like garbage and gibberish), then they are corrupt: move those out of the folder and let the game remake them. They are located in `\Steam\SteamApps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries\SETTINGS`

Comment: You might also try making an nvidia profile for each game and disable texture caching.

Answer (score 3):

Your 460 supports DX12 but not the full set of DX12 features. Any game that uses a feature that your 460 doesn't support will most likely crash. I am guessing this is what is happening here.

More info here: http://www.polygon.com/2015/1/22/7874793/directx-12-wont-require-a-new-graphics-card-after-all

Comment: I have DX11, which is the best version I can have for Win7 as I understand. And Dh2 actually worked on my laptop with DX11 and an even worse hybrid GeForce GT 620M, it worked awfully and crashed only because of the lack of memory, but I managed to play the beginning missions

Comment: Ok, you never mentioned Windows 7 in the OP, new piece of information. The crash is still most likely your GPU still, I'm not sure exactly what it would be but there is something D2 and NMS are using in newer GPUs than yours doesn't support. You have probably made sure you are on the latest drivers but I would double check. But you can't do much when your specs are below the minimum and your game crashes, they have minimum specs for a reason.

Comment: Windows 7 doesn't support DX12, so their hardware not having full support for it is immaterial and not the cause for the crashes

Answer (score -1):

I don't know specifically why this happens, but for some reason, the default resolution is set too low for the game to load properly.

While the loading screen is happening in Dishonored 2, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - this will force it into windowed mode, and actually let you into the main menu. From there, you can change the settings however you want. Just make sure you change the resolution before you save and quit, or you'll have to do this all again.

Comment: Would appreciate an explanation on downvote, since this solved the problem for me.